# How to create a word file from an existing XML file data with all the settings(format & alignments) using openxml method in VB.NET?

Tags: xml, vb.net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am having a XML file generated in run time on my program.This XMLfile.InnerText() is having some formats(Like -enter,spaces,tab,Alignments) as below,

This a test of the windows driver

2115 -XXXXXXXXXX BRANCH XXXX

XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXXXX XX

XXXXXXXXXX : 08/23/16
XXX XXX:

08/23/19
XXXXXXXX XXXXXX : 9

---

XXXXXX XXX X

XXXX: XXX 0,01

XXXXXX XXX

XXXXX:1

### XXXXXXXXX

I am trying create a word document with this XMLfile.InnerText(with this above format& alignments) using VB.net(provided the used code as example).

```
Dim vWordDoc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(tmppath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)

                ' Set the content of the document so that Word can open it.
                Dim vMainPart As MainDocumentPart = vWordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart()

                ' Create the document structure and add some text.
                vMainPart.Document = New Document()

                Dim vBody As Body = vMainPart.Document.AppendChild(New Body())
                Dim vPara As Paragraph = vBody.AppendChild(New Paragraph())
                Dim run As Run = vPara.AppendChild(New Run())
                run.AppendChild(New Text(XMLFile.InnerText))
                vMainPart.Document.Save()
                vWordDoc.Close()
```

By using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application -> Range.InsertXML()` method i am able to bring this same format in the word file.

But i want to capture the same XML format in my newly created word file by using OpenXML method?

Answer (score 0):

The Word UI/classic object model automates many things that aren't available when working directly with the file contents when they aren't open in the Word application. `InsertXML` essentially performs a conversion of the XML to Word content. There is no direct equivalent in the Open XML SDK.

What the Open XML SDK does have is [AlternativeFormatImportPart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.alternativeformatimportpart?view=openxml-2.8.1), [AlternativeFormatImportPartType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.alternativeformatimportparttype?view=openxml-2.8.1), and [altChunk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk?view=openxml-2.8.1).

According to the Enum documentation, XML is a valid file format for this approach. Whether the result will be the same as `InsertXML` you'd have to test. The altChunk link contains sample code you can use for a starting point, which I copy here for easy reference.

```
using System.Linq;  
using System.IO;  
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;  
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;  
namespace altChunk  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {            
            string fileName1 = @"c:\Users\Public\Documents\Destination.docx";  
            string fileName2 = @"c:\Users\Public\Documents\Source.docx";  
            string testFile = @"c:\Users\Public\Documents\Test.docx";  
            File.Delete(fileName1);  
            File.Copy(testFile, fileName1);  
            using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc =  
                WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName1, true))  
            {  
                string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";  
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;  
                AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk =   
                    mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(  
                    AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);  
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(fileName2, FileMode.Open))  
                    chunk.FeedData(fileStream);  
                AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();  
                altChunk.Id = altChunkId;  
                mainPart.Document  
                    .Body  
                    .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body  
                    .Elements<Paragraph>().Last());  
                mainPart.Document.Save();  
            }             
        }  
    }  
}
```

What this approach does is to store the external content as part of the ZIP package. When Word opens the file it performs the conversion, integrating the content into the Word document. The stored content is removed in the process.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information. I tried this code.. but i am getting this Error: "Object reference not set to an instance" in this particular line - mainPart.Document  
                    .Body  
                    .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body  
                    .Elements<Paragraph>().Last());

My i know what is the reason for this error ? Could you please tell me the solution...